# Come back or came back?

Tags: grammaticality

> "A few hours had passed and Yukino had still not come back to them."

Is this correct or should it be came?

Comment: 'come back'. the sentence is correct the way it is. if you wanted to use 'came', then you could rephrase it to say "A few hours had passed and they hoped Yukino would have 'came back' to them".

Comment: @chornge, your second statement is incorrect. The past participle of _to come_ is "come." The past participle is used in all perfect constructions, i.e. after all conjugations of _have._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The past participle form of "come" is also "come." Since past perfect tenses use past participle form a verb, "Yukino had still not come back to them" is correct. See https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/simple-past-or-past-participle for more details.

Comment: Hi Math Lover. Your answer is technically correct, but ELU is looking for answers that provide context and external references that back up statements. See [this topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center for more information.